# Ignore directives when parsing haskell modules

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-src-exts

I am using `haskell-src-exts` package to parse the `import` declarations inside a module, here is the code I am using

```
importNames :: FilePath -> IO ()
importNames fname =  do
let pMode = parseMode fname
parsed <- P.parseFileWithMode pMode fname
case parsed of
  P.ParseOk m -> do
    let names  = modNames m
    putStrLn $ P.prettyPrint
  P.ParseFailed srcLoc message -> do
    putStrLn $ unlines [P.prettyPrint srcLoc , message]

-- | Extract all imports from a Module
extractImports :: Module -> [ImportDecl]
extractImports (Module _ _ _ _ _ imports _) = imports

modNames :: Module -> S.Set ModuleName
modNames m = foldr (\i r -> S.insert (importModule i) r) 
             S.empty $ extractImports m
```

This failes as soon as the parser hits a `#ifdef` directive.

Is this supposed to happen, can `haskell-src-exts` ignore those and carry on?

Thanks.

Comment: You could pipe the preprocessor into your program.

Comment: What kind of result would you expect the parser to produce? The parser returns an AST, while the preprocessor works at the token level. There is no reasonable way to define an AST without running the CPP, so that e.g. only a branch in an #ifdef/#else/#endif is chosen.

Comment: I see thanks!
I added a single pass of cpphs and it seems to fix the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't want to do that. A Haskell module written using CPP generally won't parse, let alone make any sense, if you ignore the CPP. As [Gurkenglas suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38359356/ignore-directives-when-parsing-haskell-modules#comment64131262_38359356), the solution is to run the preprocessor before attempting to parse the file.